# How to pass an array from controller to PHP file that contains CSS before the view is loaded?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

My goal is: Change the CSS file from value I get from a database

**Course of actions:**

Enter 'red' in textbox of view Page1.php and submit.

Page1.js send value in ajax to Page2_Controller which call Settings_model to add value in database.

**Here is my problem..**

I need to get the 'red' setting from the database and send it to the settings.php (which is the CSS) **before** the Page2.php view is called.

**View 1**

*I call the php/css file*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/settings.php">
```

**Controller 1** in the index before the view is loaded:

```
$data['settings'] = $this->settings_model->getSettings();
```

**settings_model:**

```
public function getSettings()
```

And now what I want to do is send my settings to the settings.php file which contain:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    (get my array here)
    $userNameColor = the value from the array;
?>
#userName{
   color:$userNameColor;
}
```

Comment: Which MVC and do I understand that your controller is `css` and the function in this controller something like `actionSettings`? (Where php is not needed) - right now I just think there is a big lack of knowledge about what you are doing there. What is your main goal? Get CSS data from DB and push it out?

Comment: CodeIgniter and yes I agree my question isn't clear. I will edit my question to show the course of actions I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can always echo your strings on the css of the page:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
   #userName{
<?PHP 
$css = $data['settings'];//or whatever your data is called
foreach($css as $key => $value)
{
?>    
     <?= $key?> : <?= $value?>;
<?PHP
}
?>
   }
 </STYLE>
```

Comment: UPPER CASE HTML? `:-O`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#userName{
   color: <?php echo $userNameColor ?>
}
```

or

```
#userName{
   color: <?= $userNameColor ?>
}
```

you need to embed php code outputs the value of the variable in the css file